# Select data with specific fieldName

Tags: android, database, realm

I'm working Realm .Here is a my RealmObject class

```
public class Transactions extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

@Index
@PrimaryKey
private long id;
private String amount = "";
private String transactionStatus = "";
private String signature = "";
private String dateTime = "";
private String paymentType = "";
private String companyId = "";
private String company = "";
private String companyIdentification = "";
private String address = "";
private String serialNumber = "";
private String terminalId = "";
private String additionalText = "";
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getTransactionStatus() {
    return transactionStatus;
}

public void setTransactionStatus(String transactionStatus) {
    this.transactionStatus = transactionStatus;
}
public String getSignature() {
    return signature;
}

public void setSignature(String signature) {
    this.signature = signature;
}


public String getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}

public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}


public String getPaymentType() {
    return paymentType;
}

public void setPaymentType(String paymentType) {
    this.paymentType = paymentType;
}

public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public String getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
}

public void setCompanyId(String companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
}

public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public String getCompanyIdentification() {
    return companyIdentification;
}

public void setCompanyIdentification(String companyIdentification) {
    this.companyIdentification = companyIdentification;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getSerialNumber() {
    return serialNumber;
}

public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
    this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
}

public String getTerminalId() {
    return terminalId;
}

public void setTerminalId(String terminalId) {
    this.terminalId = terminalId;
}

public String getAdditionalText() {
    return additionalText;
}

public void setAdditionalText(String additionalText) {
    this.additionalText = additionalText;
}
```

}
My goal is to select item with two conditions
1 ) Amount between  1.00 --- 10.00

2 ) Date between  1.2.2018 -- 12.2.2018 (for example)

I try to select data with amount like this but result is emply

```
    final RealmResults<Transactions> transactions = realm.where(Transactions.class)
                        .between("amount", 0, 10)
                        .findAllSorted("id", Sort.DESCENDING);
```

How I can select item with my conditions (select with amount or date)
thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't work because your data types are wrong.

```
private String amount
private String dateTime
```

Should be

```
private int amount;
private Date dateTime;
```